# Hide Footer On Mobile & Tablet

Tags: html, css, joomla, footer

I am wanting to hide my footer on mobile and tablet devices. I have looked all over google for some help but haven't found anything. The HTML code for my footer is,

```
<!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="container<?php echo ($params->get('fluidContainer') ? '-fluid' : ''); ?>">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="none" />
          <div class="footer">
&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php echo $sitename; ?>
            </div>
```

CSS code for my footer is,

```
.footer {
  background-color: #F6861F;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-bottom: 0
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you failed to find this information on google. It is available ad-nauseam ;-) Try searching for "css hide on mobile"

Answer (score 2):

After the mobile first strategy you should first hide the footer and then display it for desktops only.

```
.footer {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .footer {
    display: block;
    background-color: #F6861F;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-bottom: 0
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .footer{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 80px) {
  .hidden_mobile {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
  }
}

Comment: Have tried using this but it's still not doing anything. Have read some tutorials online and don't know what i'm doing wrong. Could you give me some advise?

Answer (score 0):

Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ks1q8nkt/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .footer{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The code means that every class, id and element which is defined in the block will respond for all devices which have a max width of 600 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write @media for that in css for your mobile width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
 .footer{
     visibility: hidden;
     display: none;
 }
}
```

For small mobile and you can change the width according to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS from other people. Alternately if you are using the Bootstrap framework (baked into most Joomla templates) just add the appropriate column visibility classes:

```
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm container<?php echo ($params->get('fluidContainer') ? '-fluid' : ''); ?>">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="none" />
        <div class="footer">
            &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?php echo $sitename; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I added **hidden-xs** and **hidden-sm** to the `div` class list in front of the container.  See here:  [Bootstrap Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

NOTE: those two classes are for the most recent version of Bootstrap.  For version 2.3.2 you need to read here:  [Bootstrap v2.3.2 Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this CSS code.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .footer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```